# htaccess rewriterule conversion for subdomain

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a directory indexer on my site that has index.php?dir= in its pathway.
In order to hide that bit from URL, I had the following perfectly working htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /downloads

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^dir=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)? index.php?dir=$1/ [L,QSA]
```

As you can see from the htaccess above, this directory indexer was in

```
www.example.com/downloads
```

and the htaccess lied in it.
Now I have decided to move the folder 'downloads' to a sub-domain on a different server on a different host so

```
www.example.com/downloads
```

will be redirected to

```
downloads.example.com
```

which will be on another host.
Can someone please modify the htaccess above so that it now works on

```
downloads.example.com
```

Comment: Try removing **RewriteBase /downloads** as there is no subdirectory in the new domain.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something like this and put this htaccess file *in the document root of your **downloads.example.com** domain**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} downloads.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^dir=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} downloads.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)? index.php?dir=$1/ [L,QSA]
```